# GDXPay, failed to bind to service on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, in-app-billing, robovm

I've implemented GDXPay into my Libgdx application and it works completely fine for ios.  When I try to run Android, I get the error "failed to bind to service".

```
- error installing purchase manager: com.badlogic.gdx.pay.android.googleplay.GdxPayException: Failed to bind to service
08-24 11:07:23.162 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err: com.badlogic.gdx.pay.android.googleplay.GdxPayException: Failed to bind to service
08-24 11:07:23.164 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.android.googleplay.AndroidGooglePlayPurchaseManager$1.disconnected(AndroidGooglePlayPurchaseManager.java:119)
08-24 11:07:23.164 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.android.googleplay.billing.V3GoogleInAppBillingService.bindBillingServiceConnectionToActivity(V3GoogleInAppBillingService.java:111)
08-24 11:07:23.164 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.android.googleplay.billing.V3GoogleInAppBillingService.reconnectToHandleDeadObjectExceptions(V3GoogleInAppBillingService.java:183)
08-24 11:07:23.164 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.android.googleplay.billing.V3GoogleInAppBillingService.internalStartPurchaseRequest(V3GoogleInAppBillingService.java:158)
08-24 11:07:23.164 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.android.googleplay.billing.V3GoogleInAppBillingService.startPurchaseRequest(V3GoogleInAppBillingService.java:139)
08-24 11:07:23.164 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.android.googleplay.AndroidGooglePlayPurchaseManager.purchase(AndroidGooglePlayPurchaseManager.java:196)
08-24 11:07:23.164 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.PurchaseSystem.purchase(PurchaseSystem.java:148)
08-24 11:07:23.164 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.GDXPay.buyItem(GDXPay.java:154)
08-24 11:07:23.165 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.states.CharacterSelectionState.handleInput(CharacterSelectionState.java:133)
08-24 11:07:23.165 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.states.CharacterSelectionState.update(CharacterSelectionState.java:147)
08-24 11:07:23.165 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.states.Hud.update(Hud.java:94)
08-24 11:07:23.165 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.states.GameStateManager.update(GameStateManager.java:162)
08-24 11:07:23.165 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.KangarooGame.render(KangarooGame.java:73)
08-24 11:07:23.166 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:459)
08-24 11:07:23.166 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1535)
08-24 11:07:23.166 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
08-24 11:07:23.180 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err: Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.pay.android.googleplay.GdxPayException: bindService() returns false.
08-24 11:07:23.180 3097-3124/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:   ... 15 more
```